# In zephyr-rtos, how to set compilation `-O0` flags at build time?

Tags: zephyr-rtos

In zephyr-rtos, how to set compilation `-O0` flags at build time?

I'am new to both embedded/rtos dev and zephyr. Following the official zephyr doc, I managed to install zephyr/west and build/flash/run the blinky example that works from-debian-on-the-board.

Following the doc, `west debug` runs fine but it seems the build is done in RelWithDebInfo by default so the `gdb` doesn't have all infos at debug time.

How to pass `-O0` at build time to get full scope debugging latter on with `west debug`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set `-O0`, you can provide the KConfig `CONFIG_NO_OPTIMIZATIONS` option to west. Command for blinky sample application:

```
west build samples/basic/blinky -CONFIG_NO_OPTIMIZATIONS=y
```

For debugging, `-Og` might be a better choice:

```
west build samples/basic/blinky -DCONFIG_DEBUG_OPTIMIZATIONS=y
```

You can set the KConfig option also in *prf.conf* of your app. For the blinky sample set `DCONFIG_DEBUG_OPTIMIZATIONS=y` in *zephyr/samples/basic/blinky/prj.conf*.

See also [KConfig search](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/kconfig.html) documentation.